# Visually-transparent & Input-transparent Windows

Tags: gnome, opensuse, window-manager, java

I'm a Java programmer who's rather new to Linux. I'm on Suse / Gnome and I need to create a window which:

- Is visually translucent/transparent. This is the usual alpha blending
  that composes a foreground image with a background image, while
  allowing the background image to be visible "through" the foreground
  image.
- Is transparent to mouse events, in other words the window accepts no
  mouse events and all such event are passed through to whatever lies
  underneath.

I successfully got the visual transparency but not the mouse event transparency.
When I test the environment translucency capabilies with Java I got that:

```
 - TRANSLUCENT = false
 - PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT = true
 - PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT = true
```

The compositing is activated. I changed compositing type from OpenGL to XRender and vice versa. But it didn't change anything. Do I have to change of Window Manager or activate some options?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Transparency to mouse events you will have to program as window behavior. Visualy transparent is something the windowing system you select provide.